# Laravel format time column in blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In Laravel I know I can use Carbon to format dates into more readable strings. Is there a way to do this for a `time` column like `{{ $event->time->format('h i') }}`? All I see in all my searches are related to `datetime` columns. A lot of the apps I do are for schedules so there is a "Start" time and "End" time. For these I use `$table->time('starts');` in my migrations, not a timestamp. The trouble is when I use the field in Blade, I need to format it in 12 hr AM/PM format and I can never find a good way.

Comment: I think you should use unix time stamp instead, and carbon can help format it easily.

Comment: @Whales_Corps I understand a time stamp would allow me to do that. I am just wondering if there is anything similar if I did prefer to use a time column instead.

Comment: Advice: store both date and time in a single column for events. Reason: timezones. Best example is watching US-based PPV events in the UK. It’ll start one day in the US, but will actually already be the next day in the UK as it’ll be after midnight, local time.

Comment: @Packy can you confirm if the answer below work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

try

in the model make sure you have the field in the cast array

```
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime:h i',
];


$event->time->format('h i')->toTimeString()
```

try below also

```
public function getformattedAttribute()
{
    return \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('h i', $this->attributes['time']);
}
```

and run it with $event->formatted

Comment: That returns "Call to a member function format() on string". I think since I cant cast `$event->time` as a `date` in blade it just returns as a string

Comment: looks like you are not having the field in the cast array at the model, I updated my answer, please check

Comment: Still an error. `Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. ` Have you tried this with a `time` column? Not datetime or timestamp

Comment: hmm, are you sure you have valid data in the column , let me update the answer with another method

Comment: I just updated my answer, I'm afraid that `time` field is making issues as it can be reserved and used for internal use, however, try the above and lets see

Comment: Anything with Carbon wont work. I had to do it like this `public function getFormattedStartsAttribute()
    {
        return date("g:i a", strtotime($this->starts));
    }`

Comment: can you try renaming your column with something other than time and try

Comment: Sorry, I used 'time' just in the example. The column name is actually `starts` so the name doesnt have anything to do with it

Answer (score 0):

> Depending on your implementation, you might have some unreliable time generated on conversion, basically because of timezone so I will post with the assumption that you're using something like below:
>   `$table->timeTz('start');` or `$table->time('start');`
>   The Difference there is the timezone which can produce incorrect value on conversion as mentioned above.
>
> So, for you to generate format such as 12hr AM/PM which in reality should look like 12:00 PM or 12:00pm or 12:30 PM .....
>
> We can do something like below:

```
public function dateTest(){

    $sampleTimeFromDb = "12:00:00"; //This is the basic sample time you're expected to get from your db ...
    $sampleTimeFromDbFormated = Carbon::createFromTimeString($sampleTimeFromDb)->format('g:i a'); // am/pm, you can change a to A to get AM/PM


//Other samples which basically will generate same sample but with time stamp specified
$sampleCurrentTimeLag = Carbon::createFromTimeString("12:00:00","Africa/Lagos");
$sampleCurrentTimeReg = Carbon::createFromTimeString("01:00:00","America/Regina");


$def_format_ = Carbon::createFromTimeString($sampleCurrentTimeLag)->format('g:i A'); //Without timezone AM/PM
$lagosFormat = Carbon::createFromTimeString($sampleCurrentTimeLag, "Africa/Lagos")->format('g:i a');; //with timezone am/pm

$def_format_0 = Carbon::createFromTimeString($sampleCurrentTimeReg)->format('g:i A'); //Without timezone AM/PM
$americaFormat = Carbon::createFromTimeString($sampleCurrentTimeReg, "America/Regina")->format('g:i a');; //with timezone am/pm


$data = [
    '_' => $sampleTimeFromDbFormated,
    'a' => $def_format_,
    'b' => $lagosFormat,
    'c' => $def_format_0,
    'd' => $americaFormat,
    'e' => $americaFormat
];

return View("playground", $data);
```

}

My view `playground.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>{{$_}}</p>
<p>{{$a}}</p>
<p>{{$b}}</p>
<p>{{$c}}</p>
<p>{{$d}}</p>
<p>{{$e}}</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Output: 
[image]

Hopefully it does help.